Custom validation error message for input not working in Backstage
I am creating a custom template for creating a GitHub repository, I have added a regex which should accept a specific kind of string input. But when the validation fails, I get a different error. I followed the Backstage Documentation for it, still I get the error. How do I get the error message working?
template.yaml
apiVersion: scaffolder.backstage.io/v1beta3
kind: Template
# some metadata about the template itself
metadata:
  name: misc-config-Template
  title:  Misc Config Repo Template
  description: This template will be used for creating misc-config repos
  annotations:
    github.com/project-slug: backstage/backstage
spec:
  owner: xyz
  type: GitHub

  # these are the steps which are rendered in the frontend with the form input
    # these are the steps which are rendered in the frontend with the form input
  parameters:
    - title: Name of the catalog component
      required:
        - name
      properties:
        name:
          title: Name
          type: string
          description: Unique name of the component
          pattern: '^[a-z]{3}-deployment-config$'
          ui:autofocus: true
          ui:options:
            rows: 5
        owner:
          title: Name of the owner/organisation
          type: string
          description: Unique name of the component
          placeholder: "Name of the owner/organisation"
          ui:options:
          enum:
            - 'abc-def'
      errorMessage:
        properties:
          name: 'Input should be <xyz>-deployment-config'
          owner: 'Input should be firstName-lastName'

Output Displayed:
must match pattern '^[a-z]{3}-deployment-config$'

Expected Output :
Input should be <xyz>-deployment-config


I was using the latest version 1.29 and this feature was to be updated in next version 1.30.0 to be released on 20th August, 2024.
